# What is the default timeout for GoogleApiClient connect()?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have searched through the documentation and can't find anything indicating what the default timeout is when calling

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

I know that I can make a blockingConnect call asynchronously and specify a timeout, but I would prefer to use the connect method.

Comment: You can always spawn off an AsyncTask and call the blocking connect on the task.  That will make it asynchronous with respect to the thread that launches the task.  Just make sure that if you have other tasks running that your use executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) so it truly works in parallel.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can use the blocking connect, I just wanted to know what the timeout was, if any, on the connect() call